# SQL - Filtering within a window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

*I'm using SQL Server 2014*

I am trying to remove some noise in a dataset by taking the average of all values in the 90th percentile of a group. Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT EventLocation,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(.90) 
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime)) ASC) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY EventLocation) 
        AS 'P90',
    AVG(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime))
        OVER (PARTITION BY EventLocation) 
        AS 'Mean'
  FROM MyTable
  ORDER BY N DESC
```

Currently there are 2 calculated columns:

- The 90th percentile value (of `PARTITION` population)
- The mean (of `PARTITION` population)

**I Want to add another column for:**

- **The mean of values (in a `PARTITION` population) <= the 90th percentile value (of that `PARTITION` population)**

Something like:

```
AVG(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime))
    OVER (PARTITION BY EventLocation) 
    HAVING (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime) <= [ 90th percentile value ])
    AS 'Mean90'
```

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this since it is referencing the 90th percentile value that was just deifned in `P90`...maybe a user-defined function applied group-wise, creating multiple tables and joining them, or something else.

Comment: If you use SQLserver 2014 with this question have the tag mysql?

Comment: I think you need to use a subquery or CTE for this.

Answer (score 4):

As Gordon said, a CTE is a common way to solve a problem like this. Store the results of your original query in the CTE, then select the content of the CTE and add the work you want done using the column aliases you defined.

```
;WITH IntermediateResults AS (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT EventLocation,
        PERCENTILE_CONT(.90) 
            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime)) ASC) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY EventLocation) 
            AS 'P90',
        AVG(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime))
            OVER (PARTITION BY EventLocation) 
            AS 'Mean'
    FROM MyTable
    ORDER BY N DESC
)

SELECT
    *,
    AVG(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime))
        OVER (PARTITION BY EventLocation) 
        HAVING (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime) <= P90)
        AS 'Mean90'
FROM IntermediateResults
```